# looping through list of lists

Tags: python

How can I do this:  `coord + float(y) - float(x)`

```
out = [[ coord - float(y) for v in V ] for y in y_coord ] 
out = [[ coord + float(x) for v in V ] for x in x_coord ]
```

Comment: This looks perfectly valid, the only question is whether it does what you want. Since you're asking, I'd guess it doesn't do what you want. So the question is: What do you want? **tl;dr;** Please enhance your question!

Comment: Why are you iterating over V? Your expression doesn't do anything with v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
out = [[coord + float(y) - float(x) for v in V] for x,y in zip(x_coord, y_coord)]
```